Can I have the same sub topic under 2 different featured topics?
Our Community currently has various sub-topics and our current menu only allows sub-topics to be listed on a single main-topic. There is no option to add a sub-topic to multiple main-topics.
Unfortunately once a Sub-Topic is created under one Navigational Topic it cannot be reused under another Navigational Topic.
In light of building out new sub-topics for our communities that will be applicable to multiple main-topics, I wanted to ask if there were any Salesforce plug-in's that we can install that will allow us to create a navigation menu.
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
